# How do I convert a mixed case array to lowercase using the map function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to convert a javascript mixed case Array to lowercase.  I've been searching for solutions, but the answers I am finding are for C#, C, or Java.  Can anyone give me suggestions on how to proceed?

Here's the relevant JS code I'm working with:

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(oldArray.toLowerCase);
```

Comment: var newArray = oldArray.map(function (e) { return e.toLowerCase()) or in ES2015 .map(e => e.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
let array = ["abC", "aDB", "bdD"];
let newArray = array.map((item) => {
  return item.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Remember: the map method takes a callback with three arguments, with the first being the current value being processed in the array. Think of it as an iterative function, iterating on each item in the array. The map method must also return a value for each iteration, otherwise it will return undefined for that specific value in the process/iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
["ABC", "dEf"].map(function(item) { return item.toLowerCase(); });
oldArray.map(function(item) { return item.toLowerCase(); });
```

Depending on the language, you may prefer using [toLocaleLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) ([Turkish example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I)).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(function (val) { return val.toLowerCase(); });
```

Here is some documentation on the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(function(x){ return x.toLowerCase() })
```